# Is group calling over SIP possible with asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Is group calling (like hangout, skype) over SIP possible using asterisk ?

Comment: Are you looking for both Audio + video Or only Audio calls?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit misleading because there are 4 related functions:

- ring groups
- forked calls
- call groups
- conference calls

Most probably you are referring to conference calls here which is fully supported by Asterisk and it is described [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge).